# Unable to access method from outside of class

Tags: java, list, selenium-webdriver

I have two .java files, one file (StockWatchlistElements.java) I have declare all the elements of the page and on second file (Example.java) I used that element.

**StockWatchlistElements.java**

```
public static WebElement lnkaStockWatchlist(WebDriver driver) {
        try {
            element = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"dnn_ctr769_StockWatchList_pnlContent\"]/table/tbody/tr"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw (e);
        }
        return element;
    }
```

**Example.java**

```
List<WebElement> rows = StockWatchlistElements.lnkaStockWatchlist(driver);
        int count = rows.size();
        System.out.println("ROW COUNT : " + count);
```

Comment: you are returning a single element and assigning it to a list which is wrong, if you need list of elements then return a list from the method.

Comment: Where are elements adding to the list? Can you provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @Bohemian I have added required details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your method definition from `WebElement` to `List<WebElement>` like:

```
public static List<WebElement> lnkStockWatchlist(WebDriver driver) {
        List<WebElement> element = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            element = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"dnn_ctr769_StockWatchList_pnlContent\"]/table/tbody/tr"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw (e);
        }
        return element;
    }
```

Comment: This still returning a single element.

Comment: @pburgr it will return all elements it will find as `findElements` method returns a list not a single element

Comment: After chaining the method definition from WebElement to List<WebElement>, still its not working

Comment: it might be because your element is of type `WebElement` not a list, and also please considering pasting the errors you are getting. "Not Working" is not enough

Comment: ```return element;``` showing an error, red line comer under this

Comment: ah sorry it should be defined above the try catch block

Comment: check now please

Comment: Its working for first file, 
```List<WebElement> rows = StockWatchlistElements.tblStockWatchlist(driver);
        int count = rows.size();
        System.out.println("ROW COUNT : " + count);``` 
but in second file not able to get count

Comment: Want to get a count in second file.

Comment: Updated in description.

Comment: It is because in `Second File` you are calling wrong method named `StockWatchlistElements.tblStockWatchlist(driver);` but you wrote code in `StockWatchlistElements.lnkStockWatchlist(driver);` so replace it

Comment: updated the description, but still red line comes under "lnkaStockWatchlist"

Comment: @DarshitShah please write method names correctly here you made a `typo`. A tip for you is to see what does the error say and understand it. that will help you in debugging as you cannot just ask help on SO for each `red line` you see.